# How to implement #ifdef in python specifically towards checking for testrunner

Tags: python, unit-testing, macros, runtime, pytest

I have some code that seems to be colliding with py.test as it creates some errors with sys.stdout. It doesn't fail my test but it does complain that the unit test is attempting to write to a closed file. When I remove the part of my logging configuration that streams to the stdout, the errors go away. Furthermore, if I use unittest, which is what the original code was implemented for, the code works as expected without any premature closing of the stdout stream. Temporarily, I'd like to control which logging configuration is passed based on the test runner. Is there a way for me to check which test runner is running the test during runtime to control the logging configuration? In C I am able to have code sections that could be disabled by macro such as #ifdef. Those statements could be completely disabled by using #ifdef pre-processor directives, like this:

```
 #ifdef MACRO

 controlled text

 #endif /* MACRO */
```

What is the best way to do something similar in python specifically with which testrunner is running?

Comment: Is that by chance an interference with `pytest`'s output capturing - can you reproduce the issue when running `pytest -p no:capture -p no:logging`? Maybe you can try adding a [mcve] shielding the issue? Aside from that, there's [`PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pytest-current-test-environment-variable) env var, but as you mentioned already, shipping test-specific stuff in production code isn't neat. You could also remove the stdout handler in an autouse fixture, but IMO that's not good solution either.

Comment: I noticed using the `-s` option with the pytest command did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to achieve this was defining an environment variable and testing for it in runtime. The drawback with this method is that requires two things:

1. defining an environment variable prior to executing the script
2. adding glue code in production code (highly undesirable)

Here is an example:

```
import os
# ...
# removed for sake of brevity
# ...
'handlers': ['file'] if "pytest" in os.environ else ['console', 'file'],
# ...
```